# Is it possible to write a Romance between a hero and an anti hero?

Tags: creative-writing, characters, romance

I've been meaning to write this for a while, nevertheless there some points that I would love to have clear before doing so.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. Can you elaborate on what points you need cleared up? This is very broad as written.

Comment: You will have to provide some more details, mate...

Comment: Have you ever read any romance novels? It seems to me you are trying to write something that you have no clue about. Maybe you better start with familiarizing yourself with the genre first, e.g. by reading a few books. In many romances, the two lovers are opposed in some way. For example, in the movie *Mr. and Mrs. Smith* they have to kill each other.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, anything is possible. The question is: *how* will you write it? It's all about how the story is told.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You're the writer so that mean it's yours story to tell.

There's a lot of stories out there that had its hero involved in a romantic relationship with anti-hero or villain. Take *Batman* and *Catwoman* for example.

Answer (score 0):

A romance is possible between any characters. Sometimes they can happen between the most unlikely of characters. The most important thing to remember is that they should have natural chemistry. The more you force it, the more evident it will become to the reader.